# Is there a way to import key mappings from Visual Studio into Rider IDE?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, rider, jetbrains-rider

I would like to import all the custom key bindings I have set in VS2019 over to the Rider IDE. What are the ways I could achieve this besides manually moving each of them?

I tired export setting from the visual studio and tried importing the settings into Rider. That didn't work.

Comment: Report that to the issue track and wait for it to be worked on, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR:
It's possible on first launch of Rider. Otherwise you need to reset it to default settings.

This official blogpost explains how to do it: [import-settings-from-visual-studio-and-vs-code-to-rider](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2021/06/10/import-settings-from-visual-studio-and-vs-code-to-rider/)

After successful migration of keymaps you will see something like that in keymap:
[image]